# Is there a way to "link" several elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have 4 visible divs: 
  - 2 on top 
  - 2 on the bottom, wrapped in a container 
and 1 hidden div.

When a mouse hover over a bottom div it changes its color and changes color of one of the top divs.

When user clicks on a bottom div the hidden div appears and stays on the screen until mouse leave the container.

I use if statements to change color of divs, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing this right. Maybe there is a more simple and elegant way to do this.

So there are the questions: 
  - Do I have to use if statement here? Maybe there is a way to somehow "link" pairs of elements to reduce the amount of code?
  - What if I want a top div to stay active while hidden div is visible? Do I need to write additional function with if statements again? Wouldn't that be "do not repeat yourself" rule violation?

Code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xq9kr

Comment: when you are using javascript to set an event handler to more than one element, you might consider using classes instead of id's (ex. `$(".myClass")` and `<div class="myClass"></div><div class="myClass"></div>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can create implicit links through structure**.

For example with this HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
```

You can then select the respective div in the top via indices:

```
$('div.bottom > div').hover(function () {
    var index = $(this).toggleClass('highlight').index();
    $('div.top > div').eq(index).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

**Or you can create explicit links through data attributes and IDs**.

```
<div class="top">
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <div data-for="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div data-for="div1">Div 1</div>
</div>
```

Then select like this:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('data-for')).toggleClass('highlight');
// Or, even better if you're using jquery-1.4.3+
$('#' + $(this).data('for')).toggleClass('highlight');
```

Comment: I don't recommend the second way since it isn't valid HTML (altho it should work in every browser, if it's avoidable, then avoid it)

Comment: @JCOC661, actually the second way is quite valid as of HTML5: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/